Dokku: Deploying Rails 7.1 app hangs on "Installing date 3.3.4 with native extensions"
I have a Rails 7.1 and created a 1-click droplet on DigitalOcean that has pre-installed Dokku.
I am trying to deploy now the Rails app to production, but the deployment processed stopped at remote: #13 45.25 Installing date 3.3.4 with native extensions:

It's hanging there for 20 minutes already and still counting.
This is the second droplet that I use to deploy the application. With the first (previous) one, I had the same problem. The process lasted for over an hour with no progress, so I terminated it.
Where could be a problem here? I cannot see any error logs to investigate it further. Any advice?

Your server likely does not have enough memory to actually complete the compilation of native extensions. This is fairly common when compiling C extensions (many languages do this) or building nodejs-based applications. The issue will manifest itself in either very slow deploys - as the server pages to disk - or processes being killed due to the server being out of memory.
The fix is to either:

add swap
increase real server memory
build apps off-server and deploy a docker image

The following adds a 2GB swapfile to your server (From the dokku docs):
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0600 /dev/null /swapfile
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1k count=2048k
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
echo "/swapfile       swap    swap    auto      0       0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10
echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf

Dokku also supports deploying a docker image directly. Applications can be built in CI - for example, using the official Github Action - and then deployed via the git:from-image command (from the docs). Note that this requires a remote docker registry to work.
# replace $APP, $REGISTRY, and $IMAGE_SHA as appropriate
dokku git:from-image $APP $REGISTRY/$APP@sha256:$IMAGE_SHA

Deploying an image allows you to offload the app building to whatever is already running CI for you, decreasing the compute needed during deploy times. It may also avail you to much quicker deploys as CI servers are typically much larger/faster than VMs you might provision with your hosting provider.

It looks that the problem was the server configuration. I created a droplet with 1 CPU, 1 GB Memory and 25 GB, I upgraded the droplet to 1 CPU, 2 GB Memory and 50 GB and the deployment went through.
